# TFS 2015 Build log displaying associated changes from other project

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am pretty confused over this. My build log is displaying the build result but in the **Associated changes** & **Associated work items** area it's displaying all the list form every other projects.

For example, I am the only developer working on a small project and I get the below Build log for my build

[image]

where the blue coded changeset is my project and Red & Green changesets are different projects by different teams

Any clue anyone?

Comment: Can you check your Source Settings and make sure you're not including their code?

Comment: @DaveShaw, may be I missed something. I have setup my project as stand alone one in the source control. Can you please explain what you meant?

Comment: I was thinking you have a Workspace mapping of $/MyTeamProject but your source code for your project is in $/MyTeamProject/MyProject. This will build OK, but will checkout everyone else's code (e.g. $/MyTeamProject/OtherProject) and so the "Associate Changesets" will see changesets in other branches / repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@DaveShaw** the solution is as follows.

Initially my Workspace mapping of $/ to C:/TFS_Projects so I did not had to map my other team projects. Now I have removed the Workspace mapping and left it as $/ to MyMachineName then added the projects individually and issue is resolved.

My Current Workspace looks like:[image]