# TFS 2015 build associates additional work items and changesets with itself

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have gone through this question -[TFS 2015 Build log displaying associated changes from other project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475475/tfs-2015-build-log-displaying-associated-changes-from-other-project) -and did not identify with the solution.

In my case the build works fine, solution is being compiled and outputs are being generated. However after the builds ends, on the summary page the associated changes has changesets from all the folders under the team project and similarly the associated work items belonging to these changesets too.

Under Mapping I selected the exact folders where the solution exists.

`$/team-project/ParentFolder_Ten/myProject` which is set to `$(build.sourcesDirectory)\Source`
`$/team-project/CommonReferenceFolder` which is set to `$(build.sourcesDirectory)\Reference`

The `CommonReferenceFolder` is used across different source paths and hence is kept at a common location instead of inside `$/team-project/ParentFolder_Ten/`

Continuous Integration is enabled with Batch changes.

Include= `$/teamproject/ParentFolder_Ten/myProject`

The problem that we are seeing are:
-On the dashboard page where we see All build definitions with Completed and Queued builds, the Source Branch column is set to `$/teamproject` and not `$/teamproject/ParentFolder_Ten/myProject`. Maybe because that is the common path for both the mappings. And maybe due to this it associates all the changesets that are linked to all folders under `$/team-project` and not necessarily just `$/teamproject/ParentFolder_Ten/myProject` which is what is desired.

Due to this, though a build will be queued only when changes are made to `$/teamproject/ParentFolder_Ten/myProject` the summary page is listing changesets and associated work items that are made in `$/teamproject/SomeOtherFolder`. This kind of distorts the information associated with the build since we are interested in only the changesets that are made to `$/teamproject/ParentFolder_Ten/myProject` and not `$/teamproject`

I hope I am able to explain the problem statement clearly enough. Any help in the right direction is appreciated. In case some more clarity is required on my part, please inform.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using ?

Comment: Tfs 2015 update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems to be a known issue here: [Build summary shows incorrect Source Version.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dcdf5b95-589b-47bc-b835-d684e7f0ed97/builds-associated-with-incorrect-changesets-from-other-projects?forum=tfsbuild)   It seems the **source branch is referring to collection level** when mappings were added from other team project.

> When I create a new build definition I have **one mapped server path**
>   under the repository section.  When I run builds for this definition
>   the “Associated changes” are **only showing the changes under this
>   server path**.
>
> After I **add an another mapping under the repository section I see all
>   the changes in this repository.**
>
> When I analyze the changes in the history of the definition I see that
>   the “defaultBranch” is changed to the root server path of the
>   repository.
>
> I have tried the same in VSTS and the “defaultBranch” is not changed.

You can also go through the related disscution  in this MSDN  thread: [Builds associated with incorrect changesets from other projects](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dcdf5b95-589b-47bc-b835-d684e7f0ed97/builds-associated-with-incorrect-changesets-from-other-projects?forum=tfsbuild)

From the reply from *Byran* in this issue, it should be improved in **TFS2015 update3** or upcoming QU3

> In update3 it was improved to take mappings into consideration instead
>   of just finding the common root. But **note that technically TfsVC is
>   collection scoped** and mapping can span projects. So should be
>   improved in the upcoming QU3
>
> *Bryan [MSFT]*

Comment: Thanks @Patrick-MSFT. Those links state the same problem I am dealing with. Glad that its fixed in TFS 2015 Update 3. We were planning to migrate to TFS 15 directly, but will take a two step approach and progress to Update 3.

Comment: It was not fixed, it may have been improved but so far it has not been fixed. If you have a shared folder for your builds it will use the lowest common directory between all of the mapped folders